# Унаследование в классе

Tags: java, android

Есть клас унаследованый от веб сокет сервера, выглядит примерно так.

```
public class SimpleServer extends WebSocketServer {

    public SimpleServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
        super(address);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
        conn.send("Welcome to the server!"); //This method sends a message to the new client
        broadcast( "new connection: " + handshake.getResourceDescriptor() ); //This method sends a message to all clients connected
        System.out.println("new connection to " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress());


    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        System.out.println("closed " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " with exit code " + code + " additional info: " + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        System.out.println("received message from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress() + ": " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage( WebSocket conn, ByteBuffer message ) {
        System.out.println("received ByteBuffer from "  + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("an error occured on connection " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress()  + ":" + ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("server started successfully");




    }

}
```

и все хорошо но что если я хочу разместить содержимое этого класса в `MainActivity` который унаследован от `AppCompatActivity`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `java` нет множественного наследования, поэтому у вас при всем желании не получится активити сделать наследником `WebSocketServer`

Comment: А есть возможность передать из этого класса переменную в main класс, что то в духе  Broadcast ?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду под main астивити, то можно. Вы можете Зарегистрировать локальный броадкаст в активити,  а из SimpleServer слать сообщения.

Comment: Проблема в том, что когда я организовываю отправку из SimpleServer и дело доходит до sendBroadcast(intent); оно подсвечивается красным

Comment: Ошибка? Если да, то покажите stacktrace

Comment: пишет cannot resolve method "sendBroadcast(intent)" предлагает создать метод с таким названием

Comment: Этот метод есть у context. Вам надо пробросить контекст в SimpleServer. Также вам лучше всего инициализировать SimpleServer в сервисе в новом потоке, т.к. с сестью работать из главного потока нельзя

Comment: Как можно пробросить контекст?